# How to use many-to-one associations in CompositeUserTypes

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one, compositeusertype

does anybody have a sample on how to use a CompositeUserType that contains a many-to-one association?
How to convert the foreign key received in the 'nullSaveGet' method into the corresponding associated entity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102233/nhibernate-mapping-usertypes-with-many-to-one?